# Backbone & Marionette - Data didn't show in Region when I click to back or forward from Address Bar

Tags: marionette

I run my App in first time, data have show to Region. Then, I click to view detail data, the detail page   have show data to Region.

But when I click "back" to previous page, the data haven't show to Region, and I click to "forward" to go detail page, the data haven't show to Region too.

Although, I debug in chrome, my data have parse and return to Model.

Help me pls!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the backbone.history is started.

```
MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: I use "initialize:after", but my app don't work. So I use "before:start" thì my app work, but I click "back" to previous page, the data haven't show to Region T_T